# React Redux Cant add item into list in the state

Tags: reactjs, redux

The initialState for the list is works perfectly,
and i can found the console log in the reducre too .

However its failed to add one more item in the list.

I have checked the store after i called the "CLICK_SEARCH" action
the number of item in the List (products1) remaining 1 only(initialState that one).

**initialState3**

```
 var initialState3 = {
        products1:[{
             id: "123",
              abbreviation: "123",
              case_no: "123",
              created_dt: "31/01/2018",
              last_updated: "11:43:45"

          }]
        }
```

**reducers**

```
function ReducersForSeach(state = initialState3, action) {
      switch(action.type) {
          case 'CLICK_SEARCH': {

          console.log("search action found");

           return [ ...state,
                    {
                       id: "123",
                       abbreviation: "123",
                       case_no: "123",
                       created_dt: "31/01/2018",
                       last_updated: "11:43:45"
                     }
                   ]

          }
          default :{
              return state
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: 'reducreForSeach' has typos in the first and last word?

Comment: Also if state is supposed to be a list, I don't think you should return 0 at first

Answer (score 3):

You're currently replacing whole state. You should do like this:

```
return {
 ...state,
 products1: [...state.products1,
  { // I hope, you'll merge action.payload later
   id: "123",
   abbreviation: "123",
   case_no: "123",
   created_dt: "31/01/2018",
   last_updated: "11:43:45"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: yes , i have change to this , but the list still remaining one item only ;(