# changing a specific property of an element in array using es6 map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have arrays in my data and i need to loop through the array and for any array where the id matches with one where I need to edit,  I simply need to change the property title which is a string with another name for it say,'JOhn'
The array through which i am iterating is in the format

```
[{trackStatus: "ic", dates: Array(0), _id: "5b8510d4458a656d3a6cbf14", title: "martin"} ,{trackStatus: "ic", dates: Array(0), _id: "5b8510d4458a656d3a6cbf16", title: "rama" }]
```

Now i followed this strategy

```
array1: array1.map((topic) => {
      if( topic._id === action.payload.data._id){
          console.log('here');
          return{
              ...topic,
              title:'yama'
          }
      }
      return topic;
});
```

Is the above strategy correct because I need to understand if problem or bug that i am facing is because of this part or something else?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.. can you show the resulting object how it looks like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Redux Cant add item into list in the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036143/react-redux-cant-add-item-into-list-in-the-state)

Comment: How `action.payload.data._id` looks like?

Comment: It is just another id like the id you can see in the array .

Comment: and it is called `id`? As you have already there `_id`.

Comment: The way how id looks will not change solution.Just think as two ids  that's it .

Comment: _It is just another id like the id you can see in the array_ what do you mean by that?

Comment: I meant that you can think it this way ,say you need to match if 1111 which is action.payload.data._id is eequal to the id of topic i.e topic._id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the `title` property if `id` is matched:

```js
let array1 = [{trackStatus: "ic", dates: Array(0), _id: "5b8510d4458a656d3a6cbf14", title: "martin"} ,{trackStatus: "ic", dates: Array(0), _id: "5b8510d4458a656d3a6cbf16", title: "rama" }];
let action = {};
action.payload = {};
action.payload.data={};
action.payload.data._id = '5b8510d4458a656d3a6cbf14';

array1 = array1.map((topic) => {
   if( topic._id === action.payload.data._id){
       topic.title = 'yama';
   }
   return topic;
});
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit, though OP's code work, I think only updating the specific property is enough......thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume  `5b8510d4458a656d3a6cbf14` you need to update.

```
  let array1 = [{trackStatus: "ic", dates: Array(0), _id: "5b8510d4458a656d3a6cbf14", title: "martin"} ,{trackStatus: "ic", dates: Array(0), _id: "5b8510d4458a656d3a6cbf16", title: "rama" }];

    array1.map((i) =>{
      if(i._id == '5b8510d4458a656d3a6cbf14') i.title = 'JOhn' 
    })
    console.log(array1)
```