# React Reducer Correct Way To Return An Array With State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using axios in the action creator and redux-promise middleware to return an array of objects to a map function in the render method of my component.  When using the first return statement with ES6 spread, I get an array within an array.  How would I properly iterate through this array?  Would I use map in the reducer?  The second return statement works.  I am unclear as to why I wouldn't want just return the array by itself. Thanks!!

```
const INITIAL_STATE = [];

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_TICKET:
            return [action.payload.data, ...state];
            return action.payload.data;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `action.payload.data` in this case?  Is it also an array?  If so, how do you want the two arrays to be combined order-wise?

Comment: Yes, action.payload.data is an array.  I would like to return the network request plus the empty state.  When I do "[ ...state, action.payload.data ] I get an array with an array.  How and where would I iterate through this? Thanks!

Comment: This will help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036143/react-redux-cant-add-item-into-list-in-the-state/52036379#52036379

Comment: Has anyone found a way, where reducer sends the same array referencing to same memory address as earllier, instead of creating a new array, referencing to different memory heap address ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two main ways to combine two arrays into one:

```
const newArray = [...firstArray, ...secondArray];
// or
const newArray = firstArray.concat(secondArray);
```

Either of those will work in your case, like:

```
return state.concat(action.payload.data);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark!...that makes more sense.  Can you tell me why one might use the [...state, action.payload.data] approach?

Comment: Both are valid ways to combine two arrays.  The array spread syntax is newer, and part of the ES6 language specification.

Comment: Understand the array combination.  Understand that we shouldn't mutate the state. Don't understand why I would use return state.concat(action.payload.data); vs return action.payload.data; What "magic" is redux doing behind the scenes with state if I don't combine the arrays?

Comment: Those are two different commands.  `return action.payload.data` _only_ returns the array that was in the action.  `return state.concat(action.payload.data)` returns a new array with all of the contents of the old array, _plus_ the contents of `data`.  There's no magic - it's just a question of whether you want to _replace_ the existing state with this `data` array, or _add_ the contents of `data` array to the existing state.

Comment: Also, there truly is no "magic" in Redux. It's _your_ reducer function - Redux simply saves whatever values _your_ code returns.  You might want to look through some of the slides in my [Redux Fundamentals workshop](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/06/redux-fundamentals-workshop-slides/) to see what goes on inside (which is very little - it's really just `newState = rootReducer(oldState, action)` ).

Comment: Will do.  Thanks again for your help Mark, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this format

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { myData : [] };

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_TICKET:
            return {
               ...state, 
               myData: [...myData, ...action.payload.data]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Enhanced this answer to illustrate what the OP meant, taken from the accepted answer:

[...firstArray, ...secondArray]

Comment: Not quite what the OP was looking for in terms of state structure or return values.